# Cannot make a commit to Github (following Tutorial)

Tags: github

I´ve got the following problem: 
when I try to follow a Git tutorial, I get this weird error (see picture). Can anyone help me with this? I already googled it, but haven´t found any solution for this problem.

[image]

Comment: I don't believe you google anything ;) but for your convenience, check this link: https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=vim+caught+deadly+signal+segv&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Comment: vim is crashing with a segfault for some reason. You can avoid using vim (or any editor) on commit by providing the -m switch to the git commit command. It would look something like this: `git commit -m "fixes bug"`

Answer (score 1):

This happens, because something is wrong with your [Vim](http://www.vim.org/about.php) (the text editor that is used to write the actual commit message). You can simply use `git commit -m "some message"` to do it without using a text editor:

`git commit -m "added a new feature some files changed"`

And of course you can check if your [Vim](http://www.vim.org/about.php) is working and fix / install it if it doesn't. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the -m flag, you can also change the default editor for the comment with the following command (replace nano with the one you want):

```
git config --global core.editor nano
```

Answer (score 1):

As you guess already this error is in vim editor

'segmentation fault' error. (SEGV)

segmentation fault can happen by wide number of reasons.

some times this issue happen when vim uses different python versions,

and it can also be directed to hardware issue or an old CPU in some cases

here are some links about this vim error

[here - Vim: Caught deadly signal SEGV Segmentation fault (core dumped) #445](https://.com/python-mode/python-mode/issues/445github)

[here - Vim -p: Caught deadly signal SEGV?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/1889/vim-p-caught-deadly-signal-segv)

[and here - "Vim: Caught deadly signal SEGV" #230](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/230)

Hope this helps you